# Can I use the Windows Service bus with Federation, OAuth, or other directory?

Tags: azure, acs, servicebus, azure-active-directory, nettcprelaybinding

I intend to use the NetTcpRelayBinding with Windows Service Bus, but I need the ability to add users from directories that I don't control.

I've looked at the ServiceBus documentation for Windows Server, and I'm unsure if I can use shared access signatures with the federation abilities of ACS, or if I can use Active Directory Federation Services to accomplish this using Windows Credentials.

I looked at Azure Active Directory, and it appears that there is nothing I can do with AAD and ServiceBus for Windows Server (please correct me if I'm wrong)

**Question**

How can I add/remove authorized users to a local Windows Service Bus when they are primarily using the NetTcpRelayBinding?  (not queues or topics)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Server version of Service Bus does not support the relay service. The relay service is only available in Windows Azure Service Bus, in which case ACS and ADFS are both available. Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 only supports queues and topics. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn282142.aspx for details.

Comment: Adding text from the URL you specified...........in case link dies in the future.

Comment: In both Microsoft Azure and Windows Server, Service Bus requires access tokens for authorizing access to its messaging entities. Both share the Shared Access Secrets (SAS) authentication scheme for Service Bus namespaces as well as entities (queues and topics). However, in Windows Azure, Service Bus also supports the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Access Control (also known as Access Control Service or ACS), which is not available on Windows Server. However, on Windows Server, Service Bus supports Windows integrated

Comment: authentication (domain joined users and Active Directory user groups), which are not available in Azure.